# The tag [variables] is too similar to [variables]

Tags: discussion, support, bug, tags, tag-cleanup-request

When creating the [variables] tag, the following dialog pops out:

[image]

After clicking "Yes, I'm sure", the system throws:

[image]

**So does the [variables] tag exist or not?**

Answer (score 2):

I can see a tag synonym from [variable] to [variables] but no questions on either tag. If there is a synonym then the tag *existed* but it is entirely possible that it was emptied out as it is a meta tag (requires other tags to describe it) and it is not really relevant to this site.

It is possible that the synonym is holding a block on the proper deletion or creation of the tag.

In any case [variables] isn't a particularly useful tag for Super User. Variables are a programming thing and while we allow *some* "light" programming questions a question that focuses purely on "programming variables" would be off topic here.

Comment: Can they be removed altogether?

Comment: I'm torn on doing so. In part this is a bug that I like and blocking the creation of a tag that is borderline useless to this site is a good thing to me. On the other hand there is definitely something odd going on.

Comment: It's the synonym indeed, according to [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371844/295232) to my question on Meta.SE. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317928/295232) contains a SEDE query with a list of 'orphaned' tag synonyms like this one.